# Password field cleared when returning to page with Back button

Tags: javascript, html, input, passwords, field

There is an embedded device with a web interface. Configuration page contains various settings, including SMTP account for e-mail alerts. It's a simple HTML form with input elements, including password. When user opens the page, all fields are filled using JS with previously saved settings. The page contains also a button which causes navigation to another page containing some more settings. The problem is that when a user goes back from that page using Back button in the browser, then the password field is cleared. I suppose it's for security reasons but here it's just an annoyance. If a user goes back to the settings page and wants to change something then he has to re-enter the password each time. How can I prevent the password field from being cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Without more data it is hard to be certain what is happening. What is clear is that the password should never be filled in automatically. The concern is that someone walks away from the computer and another user then gets access to the password as it is easy to [show the clear-text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-revealer-and-passwor/fgeopcldenngppapceagonnenonklpbn?hl=en) of a browser password field.

I strongly recommend against you doing anything to automatically fill in the password. That said here's my thoughts.

The only thing I can think of would involve a custom (ie: one you write yourself) [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) script. Perhaps you can record the password in the script and then reinsert it. If you really want to go security-free you can try to change the password input to a regular input field. That may cause the browser to automatically fill it in for you.

Comment: Thanks for response but it seem's I wasn't clear enough. What I'm talking about is not a login page and I don't want anything to be filled by a browser. It's a configuration page just like WiFi configuration page in a wireless router where you can set up a password for your WiFi network. When a user clicks Save button ale the fields are sent to web server using JSON. If a user clicks a link on that page, then goes back and clikcks Save then the password is reset because the browser clear the password field. Probably it's secure but not convenient for a user.